# how to fetch two datepicker values and pass into two strings

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am developing an app where i can take start and end date from datepicker and pass it to server. I successfully develop two datepicker by copying code from internet but now i dont know how to put the value of these datepickers in two different string. So that i can pass it to server.
here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ggreenb"
tools:context="com.example.viren.cable.unpaid_cust">

<TextView android:text="Set a Range"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/startbt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Set Date"


    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/endbt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Set Date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/startdateview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startbt"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview1"
    android:text="DD/MM/YYYY"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>\

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/enddateview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/endbt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview1"
    android:text="DD/MM/YYYY"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/area_spinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startdateview"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    >

</Spinner>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="submit"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/submitdatebt"
android:layout_below="@+id/startdateview"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my java code..

```
package com.example.viren.cable;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;  
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class unpaid_cust extends ActionBarActivity {
String startdate, enddate;

Button startbt, endbt, subbt;
TextView starttv, endtv;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
private DatePicker datePicker;
private Calendar startDate, endDate;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener from_dateListener, to_dateListener;

int from_year, from_month, from_day, to_year, to_month, to_day;
private final int DATE_PICKER_TO = 0;
private final int DATE_PICKER_FROM = 1;
int cur = 0;
String[] area_list;
private TextView activeDateDisplay;
private Calendar activeDate;
Spinner sp;
//private int year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_unpaid_cust);
    startbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbt);
    endbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endbt);
    subbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitdatebt);
    starttv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startdateview);
    endtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enddateview);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.area_spinner);
    area_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.area_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, area_list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String area = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    subbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitdatebt);
    subbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //new Postdate().execute();
            Toast.makeText(unpaid_cust.this, "from " + startdate + " to " + enddate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    startDate = Calendar.getInstance();


    startbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog(starttv, startDate);
                }
    });


    endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            endbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog(endtv, endDate);

 }        });


    updateDisplay(starttv, startDate);
    updateDisplay(endtv, endDate);

}

private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    dateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));

}

public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
    activeDate = date;
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        startdate=year+"-"+monthOfYear+"-"+dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
        unregisterDateDisplay();
    }
};


private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
    activeDateDisplay = null;
    activeDate = null;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            break;
    }
}

}
```

In above java code, i have two strings **startdate** and **enddate** and i want to put startdateview value in startdate and enddateview value in enddate..
help me..

Comment: After getting values from DatePickers make two calendars from that values and send calendar.getTimeInMillis()

Comment: @KhizarHayat thnx fr comment but i did study for datepicker dialog and i also modify my code and get what i want. see my new code.. i will post in answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you Idea,.. Please don’t compare with your code. You can modify it according to your requirement

```
datePicker.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // selectdate = monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/"
                        // + year;


                        selectdate = datePicker.getSelectedMonth() + "/"
                                + datePicker.getSelectedDate() + "/"
                                + datePicker.getSelectedYear();
                        String date_current = txt_datedisplay.getText().toString();
```

And make a class which extends DatePickerDialog. full code is here

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

```
public static int mYear, mMonth, mDate, selectedYear, selectedMonth,
        selectedDate;
public static int dateflag = 0;
public static int dateflag2 = 0;

public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
        int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    mYear = year;
    mMonth = monthOfYear;
    mDate = dayOfMonth;

    selectedYear = year;
    selectedDate = dayOfMonth;
    selectedMonth = monthOfYear;

}

@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selectedYear = year;
    selectedDate = day;
    selectedMonth = month;
    super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
}

// @Override
// public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
// {
// // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
//
// view.updateDate(year, month, day);
// }

public int getSelectedYear() {
    return selectedYear;
}

public int getSelectedMonth() {
    return selectedMonth + 1;
}

public int getSelectedDate() {
    return selectedDate;
}
```

}

Comment: thnx fr comment but i did study for datepicker dialog and i also modify my code and get what i want. see my new code.. i will post in answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Better u refactor ur code to be easily readable... use java conventions like the class name!
set ur two infamous `String variable` with initial strings and how do u handle dialog imports
use log around the code

`updateDisplay(starttv, startDate);
    updateDisplay(endtv, endDate);`

Comment: thnx fr comment but i did study for datepicker dialog and i also modify my code and get what i want. see my new code.. i will post in answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

I just modify my code.. earlier i copied datepicker code but now i own write my step by step and got what i want.

Here is modified Java code..

```
public class unpaid_cust extends ActionBarActivity {
String startdate, enddate;
Button startbt, endbt, subbt;
TextView starttv, endtv;
  private DatePicker datePicker;
private Calendar startDate, endDate;


int from_year, from_month, from_day, to_year, to_month, to_day;
static final int DATE_PICKER_TO = 0;
static final int DATE_PICKER_FROM = 1;

String[] area_list;
private TextView activeDateDisplay;
private Calendar activeDate;
Spinner sp;
//private int year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2;

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                from_year = year;
                from_month = monthOfYear;
                from_day = dayOfMonth;
                updateStartDisplay();
                //displayToast();
            }
        };

private void updateStartDisplay() {
    starttv.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(from_month + 1).append("/")
                    .append(from_day).append("/")
                    .append(from_year).append(" "));
startdate=starttv.getText().toString();
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener endDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                to_year = year;
                to_month = monthOfYear;
                to_day = dayOfMonth;
                updateEndDisplay();
                //displayToast();
            }
        };

private void updateEndDisplay() {
    endtv.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(to_month + 1).append("/")
                    .append(to_day).append("/")
                    .append(to_year).append(" "));
enddate=endtv.getText().toString();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_unpaid_cust);
    startbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbt);
    endbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endbt);
    subbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitdatebt);
    starttv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startdateview);
    endtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enddateview);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.area_spinner);
    area_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.area_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, area_list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String area = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    subbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitdatebt);

    startbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_FROM);
        }
    });

    endbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_TO);
        }
    });

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    from_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    from_month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    from_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    to_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    to_month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    to_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    /** Display the current date in the TextView */
    updateStartDisplay();
    updateEndDisplay();

    subbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //new Postdate().execute();
            Toast.makeText(unpaid_cust.this, "from " + startdate + " to " + enddate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_FROM:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        startDateSetListener,
                        from_year, from_month, from_day);

            case DATE_PICKER_TO:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        endDateSetListener,
                        to_year, to_month, to_day);

        }
        return null;
     }}
```

In above code i got first datepicker value in **startdate** string and second datepicker value in **enddate** string